# SSRS 2008 R2 Subtracting current row from previous row where data is summed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I am fairly new to SSRS 2008 R2. Trying to convert my reports from Crystal. Thought this would be a simple task but this ended up being a pain. I have a table that is grouped by Year then Week_Number so the table looks this when run: (I am trying to create the total row)

```
     Week1   Week2   Week3   Week4
2013   1       2       5       4
2014   0       3       2       6
Total -1       1      -3       2
```

There is a row group called `Year` and column group called `Week_Number`. I have one expression in the total column `Sum(Fields!TotalProdWTD.Value)`.

I added a group footer to try create the total row. I am able to sum the column works fine, I can get the value of the last row by doing this `ReportItems!txtTotalProd.Value`. But when I try to use

```
=Previous(ReportItems!txtTotalProd.Value)
```

I get the aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers message. I believe I have to add a reference to the group to make the previous function work, just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for here.  At the bottom of the article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With your report table
Insert new row outside group below

And use your command:
Sum(Fields!TotalProdWTD.Value) to expression textbox

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to sutract year 2014 from year 2013.